# UNION in Stored Procedure COUNT

Tags: stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure which will return the results of open cases based on an entered time - i want to return the count of the cases but based on different offices. After editing my code i will also re-state my question different - which way is best to return a count instead of the actual results which i am getting now.

The Following is my stored procedure:

```
SELECT C.CaseId
FROM [Case] C
WHERE C.DateCreated <= @BeginDate
    AND C.CaseId NOT IN (SELECT CaseId FROM CaseStatusChange CSC WHERE CSC.DateClosed < @BeginDate)

UNION

-- Also need the cases that reopened and are currently open
SELECT ReOpened.CaseId FROM
(
                SELECT C.CaseId, MAX(CSC.DateReopened) AS DateReOpened 
                FROM [Case] C 
                INNER JOIN [CaseStatusChange] CSC ON C.CaseId = CSC.CaseId
                WHERE CSC.DateReopened <= @BeginDate
                GROUP BY C.CaseId
) ReOpened 
WHERE ReOpened.CaseId NOT IN 
(
                SELECT CaseId FROM CaseStatusChange 
                WHERE CaseId = ReOpened.CaseId AND 
                CaseStatusChange.DateClosed BETWEEN ReOpened.DateReopened AND @BeginDate
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: To Include OfficeId as requested:

```
SELECT  OfficeId, SUM(CaseCount)
FROM    (
            SELECT  COUNT(C.CaseId) AS CaseCount,
                    C.OfficeId
            FROM    [Case] C
            WHERE   C.DateCreated <= @BeginDate
                AND C.CaseId NOT IN (SELECT CaseId FROM CaseStatusChange CSC WHERE CSC.DateClosed < @BeginDate)
            GROUP BY C.OfficeId

            UNION ALL

            -- Also need the cases that reopened and are currently open
            SELECT  COUNT(ReOpened.CaseId) As CaseCount,
                    ReOpened.OfficeID
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT C.CaseId, MAX(CSC.DateReopened) AS DateReOpened, C.OfficeId 
                    FROM [Case] C 
                    INNER JOIN [CaseStatusChange] CSC ON C.CaseId = CSC.CaseId
                    WHERE CSC.DateReopened <= @BeginDate
                    GROUP BY C.CaseId, C.OfficeID
                ) ReOpened 
            WHERE ReOpened.CaseId NOT IN 
                    (
                        SELECT CaseId FROM CaseStatusChange 
                        WHERE CaseId = ReOpened.CaseId AND 
                        CaseStatusChange.DateClosed BETWEEN ReOpened.DateReopened AND @BeginDate
                    )
            GROUP BY OfficeID
        ) AS OpenCasesCount
GROUP BY OfficeId
```

---

You need to wrap your whole Query in an inner Query as shown below:

```
SELECT  SUM(CaseCount)
FROM    (
            SELECT  COUNT(C.CaseId) AS CaseCount
            FROM    [Case] C
            WHERE   C.DateCreated <= @BeginDate
                AND C.CaseId NOT IN (SELECT CaseId FROM CaseStatusChange CSC WHERE CSC.DateClosed < @BeginDate)

            UNION ALL

            -- Also need the cases that reopened and are currently open
            SELECT  COUNT(ReOpened.CaseId) As CaseCount 
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT C.CaseId, MAX(CSC.DateReopened) AS DateReOpened 
                    FROM [Case] C 
                    INNER JOIN [CaseStatusChange] CSC ON C.CaseId = CSC.CaseId
                    WHERE CSC.DateReopened <= @BeginDate
                    GROUP BY C.CaseId
                ) ReOpened 
            WHERE ReOpened.CaseId NOT IN 
                    (
                        SELECT CaseId FROM CaseStatusChange 
                        WHERE CaseId = ReOpened.CaseId AND 
                        CaseStatusChange.DateClosed BETWEEN ReOpened.DateReopened AND @BeginDate
                    )
        ) AS OpenCasesCount
```

Comment: Thank you! Once again u r the best.

Comment: I am sorry i know i am a pain but i wanted to also add a param for OfficeId so i can get how many open cases there are for each office. Would i add them to the inner select statements?

Comment: you need to use GROUP BY in that case, such as SELECT COUNT(C.CaseId) AS CaseCount, OfficeID ... GROUP BY OfficeID .. so, ur results will be pairs of OfficeId & Count.

Comment: is OfficeID a column in your "Case" table? or do u need a join to get it?

Comment: This looks great, but when i try to execute the procedure i get that the ReOpened.OfficeId is invalid and not contained in either an aggregate function or the Group By clause. I will to rework what i have and see what i could do as well. Thanks!

Comment: i forgot "GROUP BY OfficeID" after Reopened. Ive updated the Answer with the change.

Comment: @Akhil Thank you very much for the help - i've learned a lot from you.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the number of columns in the `SELECT` lists must match. And their data types too.

Like this:

```
select
   col1, col2, col3
from
   t1
union
select
   col1, col2, col3
from
   t2
```

In your particular case, you need to add the OfficeID and the count in the second `SELECT` list.

Comment: Yes, in the OP's example it appears that the two selects are:
SELECT C.CaseId, O.OfficeId and SELECT ReOpened.CaseId which have a different number of arguments.

Comment: There is a sneaky COUNT() in the sub select as well.

Comment: I edited my code and starting a different way hopefully it will undue some of knots